# How to download a XML dynamic-generated file in JSF?

Tags: java, xml, jsf, download

In the JSF page I have:

```
<p:commandButton value="Download" action="#{myMBean.downloadXMLFile}" />
```

In the MBean I have the following (try/catch ommited):

```
public void downloadXMLFile() {

String xml = this.getXML();//returns the whole XML but in String format.
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();  
response.setContentType("text/xml");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=file.xml");  

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(xml.getBytes());  
out.flush(); 
}
```

But when I run it, I get an IllegalStateException:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: setBufferSize() called after first write to Output Stream/Writer
```

I tried also to convert the XML String to a Document and converting it to a File but got the same error. is it really necessary in order to work?

Comment: You already started writing to the stream, but the JSF render phase doesn't know your response is finished so it attempts to render it, and fails. Since you are using `ExternalContext` you have to call `responseComplete()` on your `FacesContext` instance to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because of an attempt to render your response during the JSF render phase.

You are using a raw response object obtained via `ExternalContext`, and writing the response yourself. You must tell the JSF runtime that the response is complete so it doesn't attempt to process it.

Save a reference to your `FacesContext`:

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();
...
```

and call `responseComplete()` when you finish building your response:

```
ctx.responseComplete();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! As a note, I had also to change the page: from <p:commandButton> to <h:commandButton>

Comment: You could add `ajax="false"` to disable any default ajax processing.

Comment: Thanks @helderdarocha that's also a valuable tip! It worked with <p:commandButton> using that property.